# Set a different shell for "git submodule foreach"

Tags: bash, git

It looks like Git uses `/bin/sh` as interpreter when executing script snippets through `git submodule foreach '...'`. Is there any way to change this, e.g. to convince git to use `bin/bash` instead?

I'm not looking for the obvious solution, i.e. to just enclose the script snippet into an extra `bash -c '...'`, because that quickly ends up in quoting hell, because both `git submodule foreach` and `bash -c` should have the script snipped passed to them being enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: "*Obviously, Git uses `/bin/sh`*" Why do you think so? It's not so obvious…

Comment: My git uses zsh. Well git doesn’t. I do

Comment: Does writing the scripted action in a file (say `/tmp/script.sh`) and calling that script (say `zsh /tmp/script.sh`) count ?

Comment: As @phd remarked, I wouldn't say "obviously", but it's probably true. If so, there's probably no way to make it do otherwise, other than changing the source code. But echoing `$SHELL` and finding that it is `/bin/bash` is not surprising: the environment passed to whatever Git is running `execve` on is provided by Git in the `execve` call. That will contain whatever Git changed the environment to: Git adds some variables and adds to `$PATH`, but does not change `$SHELL`. When /bin/sh is invoked as `sh -c <command>`, it does not alter `$SHELL` either.

Comment: Meanwhile, as @LeGEC suggested, the easy way out of Shell Quoting Hell is to write the script to a file, and invoke the file. This works even if you just want to use sh constructs. (Another alternative is to mechanically quote the code, using a regex for instance to insert backslashes wherever appropriate.)

Comment: I edited my question according to the comments made by phd and torek.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path to the shell used is hard-coded when `git` is compiled.

`git submodule foreach` ultimately calls [`run_command()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.43.0/run-command.c#L994) from the `run-command.c` file, which goes through [these steps](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.43.0/run-command.c#L282) when massaging its arguments:

```
    if (strcspn(argv[0], "|&;<>()$`\\\"' \t\n*?[#~=%") != strlen(argv[0])) {
#ifndef GIT_WINDOWS_NATIVE
        strvec_push(out, SHELL_PATH);
#else
        strvec_push(out, "sh");
#endif
        strvec_push(out, "-c");

        ...
```

<sup>(code from version `2.43.0`)</sup>

On Windows the value is always `sh`. Elsewhere, the value of (compile-time constant) `SHELL_PATH` is used, which is [by default](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.43.0/git-compat-util.h#L1412) `/bin/sh`. You can check the value in your version of `git` with:

```bash
$ git var GIT_SHELL_PATH
/bin/sh
```

---

Since using another shell is as simple as writing your action in a script file and running it with said shell (either with a `#!/bin/zsh` line or with a `zsh myscript.sh` invocation), I suggest you resort to that if you need to run your actions with another shell.